# DELPHI: Crash when unloading DLL if context help is shown

Tags: delphi

We have a complex Delphi application with a main exe and several dlls.
In main form (contained in application exe) we have menubar.
On selecting a menu the corresponding dll is loaded and a form conatained in the dll is shown modal.

The scenario is as follows:

1. Press F1 and the context help for the modal form is open.
2. Close the modal form (without closing the context help).

in the source code we have:

```
result := FreeLibrary(MH);
```

And the whole application crashes with the following windows error:

```
ERROR_ALLOCATE_BUCKET
602 (0x25A)
The bucket array must be grown. Retry transaction after doing so.
```

If we first close the context help and then close the modal form everything is ok.

The strangest thing is that we have 3 dlls crashing and 3 not crashing.
The flow goes thru the same code.

There is nothing in the Windows Event Log.

I thought **as a workaround** I could force close the context help on closing the modal form before unloading the dll but I cannot find pid or some task identifier which I could kill.
There is no child processes of the application pid.

In Task Manager 'Processes' tab I see the name of our application and the name of chm-file (without .chm) like a subtask (at least seems like so) and I can right-click 'Stop task' but programatically I cannot find this...

**P.S:**
We use .chm file and do not have HtmlHelpViewer in uses of any module.
We have associated specific help topic to controls in forms so they automatically display the corresponding help topic when the user focuses it and presses F1. So in fact we do not use Application.HelpCommand(.....) to show the help

**** edited ****

Currently we use Delphi Tokyo. The product is stared 15 years ago in Delphi7. It has several dll-s (some of them are extra product modules) with plenty of forms and frames.

**** edited ****

```
**LU RD's answer solved my problem:**   
Application.HelpCommand(HELP_QUIT, 0);
```

P.S:
I cannot mark the answer as accepted. I do not know why.

Comment: Is the help displayed by the main applicaction or by the DLL, or some of each?

Comment: `Application.HelpCommand(HELP_QUIT, 0); ` should close the help.

Comment: @Dsm, We have associated specific help topic to controls in forms so they automatically display the corresponding help topic when the user focuses it and presses F1. 
So in fact we do not use Application.HelpCommand(.....) to show the help.

Comment: @LU RD, I've tried with HELP_QUIT but still crashing on FreeLibrary(...)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that we have .chm file and we do not have HtmlHelpViewer in uses of any module.
I've edited the question.

Comment: Pretty hard to say what is going on without any details. I think you'll need to debug this yourself or provide a [mcve]

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes I understand about MCVE but I cannot reproduse it in a simpler application which I could share for download here. And I do not see differences between load/unload the dlls which do not crash and these which crash when help is open.
yes, I'm debugging right now. I just hope I could get some hints like the one with Application.HelpCommand(HELP_QUIT,0)

Comment: This site isn't for us to guess and offer tips and hints. Look elsewhere for that sort of help. Here we are for questions with enough specific detail to have definitive answers. I suggest therefore that you withdraw this post.

Comment: You did not specify which Delphi version. It may be relevant.

Comment: Why, oh why do people still put forms in DLLs? For such purposes, packages are ideal.

Comment: From what I can read from this thread, [HelpCommand HELP_QUIT](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=814911), closing the help works up to XE6 and then again in 10 Seattle. In versions in between, only the help window is closed, but the help process is only terminated when the application closes.

Comment: Currently we use Delphi Tokyo. The product is stared 15 years ago in Delphi7. It has several dll-s (some of them are extra product modules) with plenty of forms and frames. (added this info to the question)

Comment: Sorry, you did not answer my question. I asked which part(s) of the application displayed the help.

Comment: I guess in this particular case the DLLs display the help.

We have associated specific help topic to controls in forms (contained in the DLL) so they automatically display the corresponding help topic when the user focuses it and presses F1.

Comment: @LURD First time I have tried Application.HelpCommand(HELP_QUIT,0) in the code where we free resources and prepare to unload the dll,

but now I've tried this in OnClose() of the problematic forms.

and it works :)   Thank you very much!

P.S: I cannot mark the answer as accepted. I don't know why

Comment: Since the question was put on hold for various reasons, it is not possible to add an answer. I will vote to reopen. Just a note, my comment was just a guess, hence it was a comment. If a question is unclear in any way, it not a custom here to add an answer before some things are clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I thought **as a workaround** I could force close the context help on closing the modal form before unloading the dll but I cannot find pid or some task identifier which I could kill. There is no child processes of the application pid".

In order to close the context help, add this line in the modal form `OnClose()` event:

```
Application.HelpCommand(HELP_QUIT, 0);
```

> **Application.HelpCommand:** Provides access to any of the Help commands in the application programming interface (API) of native Help handling functions HTMLHelp, WinHelp, or other.

See [Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HelpCommand](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HelpCommand) for further details.